# Is EditorDriver.setConstraintViolations supposed to propagate EditorError-s to child editors?

Tags: gwt, bean-validation, gwt2, requestfactory

Is `EditorDriver.setConstraintViolations` supposed to propagate `EditorError`s to child editors ?

I have `OrderEditor` that has nested `OrganizationEditor` that has nested `ContactPersonEditor`. All my editors implement only `HasEditorErrors<>` interface.

So when I call `EditorDriver.setConstraintViolations` every editor receives `HasEditorErrors.showErrors` call-back but only root `OrderEditor` gets container with errors. All nested editors receive the call with empty container.

Is it supposed to work automagically ? Or I have to subclass my driver and traverse through all editors using visitor ? And even if I do I don't understand how I'd push errors to them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it doesn't work in GWT 2.4 release. But it seems fixed in trunk version of GWT.

After compiling GWT from sources and debugging in them I discovered that errors are being propagated to the bottommost editors. Therefore if I have EditorA which consists of bunch of ValueBoxEditorDecorators I won't get EditorA.showErrors() call. It will be propagated all the way down.